# How to know if table row is extended or not

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on angular bootstrap table with extendable row, I want to know if the row is extended or not, how to do that?

Below is my code

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#extend1">
</tr>
<tr>
    <div id="extend1" class="accordian-body collapse"></div>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extend1" ng-click="isExtended ? isExtended = false : isExtended = true"></tr>
<tr>
  <div id="extend1" class="accordian-body collapse" ng-show="isExtended"></div>
</tr>
```

Then you can check via `$scope.isExtended` or just `isExtended` if doing it in your frontend.

For use in `ng-repeat`, do observe that you need to wrap your `tr`s in something for the `ng-repeat` scope to work for the extended row.

```
<div ng-repeat="row in table">
  <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extend1" ng-click="row.isExtended ? row.isExtended = false : row.isExtended = true"></tr>
  <tr>
    <div id="extend1" class="accordian-body collapse" ng-show="row.isExtended"></div>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: how does it works if he want to extend multiple rows?

Comment: @PankajParkar He didn't state that there would be multiple rows. So I didn't create an answer for that use case.

Comment: Thanks @Chrillewoodz but I will apply an ng-repeat so I will have multiple rows

Comment: @Dev Then you can bind isExtended to the ng-repeat variable. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Dev Updated answer, take a look.